# Failing to implement TF\IDF on a given dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to implement TF\IDF and I cant seem to make my code work.
I cleaned up the data, and the current situation is as such:

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: title, text.
every row is considered a document, and it's contents are the words in the corresponding list that sits in the text column.

I am trying to do the TF part first which means for every document, get the count for every word and apply log(1+count) for each word.

For the IDF part I thought that I should concat every list in the 'text' column and leaving only distinct values there, and then for every word I should count how many documents it appears in.

The problem is, I don't know how to implement these ideas to code.

I tried to separate each line to a stand alone dataframe and I got the code for it, but it takes way too much time so I cant even proceed on that direction...

What I need is the knowledge about how to apply a function on a every row of said column 'text' and applying the regular count->reducekey there to count the word for each document and get the result back in a list or a hashmap I guess.

After that, I need to find a way to concat every list and counting appearances for each word.

I have added a picture to show what I am dealing with.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here is sample code from below tutorial

```
tf_idf = {}
for i in range(N):
    tokens = processed_text[i]
    counter = Counter(tokens + processed_title[i])
    for token in np.unique(tokens):
        tf = counter[token]/words_count
        df = doc_freq(token)
        idf = np.log(N/(df+1))
        tf_idf[doc, token] = tf*idf
```

if you are python developer for more information you can use this tutorial:

https://towardsdatascience.com/tf-idf-for-document-ranking-from-scratch-in-python-on-real-world-dataset-796d339a4089